# Loop excel files and merge based on one common column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For multiple `csv` files in a folder, I hope to loop all files ends with `csv` and merge as one excel file, here I give two examples:

**first.csv**

```
     date    a    b
0  2019.1  1.0  NaN
1  2019.2  NaN  2.0
2  2019.3  3.0  2.0
3  2019.4  3.0  NaN
```

**second.csv**

```
     date    c     d
0  2019.1  1.0   NaN
1  2019.2  5.0   2.0
2  2019.3  3.0   7.0
3  2019.4  6.0   NaN
4  2019.5  NaN  10.0
```

**...**

My desired output is like this, merging them based on `date`:

```
        date    a     b    c    d
0  2019/1/31  1.0   NaN  1.0  NaN
1  2019/2/28  NaN   2.0  5.0  2.0
2  2019/3/31  3.0   2.0  3.0  7.0
3  2019/4/30  3.0   NaN  6.0  NaN
4  2019/5/31  NaN   NaN  NaN  10.0
```

I have edited the following code, but obviously there are some parts about `date` convert and merge `dfs` are incorrect:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob

dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for file_name in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    # print(file_name)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name, engine='python', skiprows=2, encoding='utf-8')
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.dropna(axis = 1)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y.%m')
    ...
    dfs = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'date', how= "outer")

# save the data frame
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
dfs.to_excel(writer,'sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: what output are you getting now?

Comment: It doesn't work for `merge`, so no result so far. For `concatenate`, the link from here is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033013/iterate-through-excel-files-and-sheets-and-concatenate-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for file_name in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name, engine='python', skiprows=2, encoding='utf-8')
    df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().str.replace('dates', 'date')
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.dropna(axis = 1)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str), format='%Y.%m') + MonthEnd(1)
    if dfs.empty:
        dfs = df.copy()
    else:
        dfs = dfs.merge(df, on='date', how="outer")
```

Comment: Thank you. Another question, if `date` columns in different dataframe are not identical, for example they could be `dates`, `Date`, or `DATE` etc, how could rename them all to `date` before merging.

Comment: @ahbon You can make them all lowercase and replace possible `dates` with `df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().str.replace('dates', 'date')`.  Added to answer.

Comment: Can we `str.replace` multiple strings to `date`? For example: `date`, `dates`, `time`, etc. replace with `date`.

Comment: @ahbon Sure, just use `|` in pattern like `'dates|time|times'`

Comment: When `merge` a lot of `df`s, `date` column has duplicated dates, do you know why?

Comment: @ahbon It must be happening because on the right side (in the file that you are opening) you have duplicated dates, so it merges each one. If this is the case it will continue multiplying each time you have duplicates for the same date. You might want to handle duplicates in `df` before merging.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `DatetimeIndex` created in `read_csv` by parameter `index_col` and `parse_dates` with `0` for first column of data and last add last day of Month in last step for improve performance:

```
dfs = []
for file_name in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name, 
                     engine='python', 
                     skiprows=2, 
                     encoding='utf-8',
                     index_col=0, 
                     parse_dates=[0])
    #if necessary some processing

    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
df.index = df.index + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
print (df)
              a    b    c     d
date                           
2019-01-31  1.0  NaN  1.0   NaN
2019-02-28  NaN  2.0  5.0   2.0
2019-03-31  3.0  2.0  3.0   7.0
2019-04-30  3.0  NaN  6.0   NaN
2019-05-31  NaN  NaN  NaN  10.0
```

Comment: Sorry, I just try with your method. I get: `ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible` for this line `df.index = df.index + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()`.

Comment: @ahbon - I create `DatetimeIndex` by `index_col` parameter, and also is used `parse_dates` paramter by first column.